# Trying to install Deepin OS beside Windows 10, no NTFS option for formatting a partition

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.howtoshout.com/dual-boot-deepin-os-winodws-10-uefi/) article to install Deepin OS beside the existing Windows 10 OS

I form a ext4 parition for the OS
and I'm trying to make another NTFS partition for /home, for purposes of having files here accessible to Windows. I see no option for NTFS... why? how do I get around that?

Comment: don't use NTFS for Linux /home [Can I use ntfs for /home](https://askubuntu.com/q/239347/253474), [Is it safe to use an NTFS volume (partition) for Linux `/home` mountpoint?](https://superuser.com/q/1239067/241386), [Is it bad to have /home/ on an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/330356/253474)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, [because Linux permissions are different](https://askubuntu.com/a/330448/433872).

There are programs for Windows that can browse ext4 file systems (e.g., [ext2fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/)). Conversely, ext4 can view NTFS systems with [ntfs-3g](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G). So you don't really need NTFS to be able to view your Linux files from Windows.

---

**Edit**: As per @GabrielaGarcia's warning, take note that using either of these drivers to access the other filesystem has a risk of causing errors for the other filesystem, so a shared, non-booting NTFS drive is a better idea.

Comment: I strongly recommend having a different data only NTFS partition to share files between the OSes. Everything in this answer is true but the warnings are missing: 1. Ext2fsd can and usually does corrupt EXT4 partitions and 2. writing to the Windows system partition from  outside is also strongly discouraged because in certain circumstances it can also make Windows fail to boot.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Those are good to know! As a casual Linux/Windows user I've never noticed these problems, but I'll heed these warnings in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ext4 as that is the most widely used Linux file system. NTFS is proprietary to Microsoft so Linux doesn't have that option to format. ext4 is also more efficient with small file operations than NTFS, just an FYI. You can also look into other file formatting such as ZFS but I do not recommend it unless you know what you're doing. Good luck :)

Edit: As for the article you have refered to, they are also using ext4 [here](https://www.howtoshout.com/dual-boot-deepin-os-winodws-10-uefi#home_Partition)